# ADODataSet: как узнать, сколько записей осталось после применения фильтра?

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли программно узнать, сколько записей осталось после применения фильтра в ADODataSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, разобрался, обычный RecordCount подходит.